How to insert the undefined entity name instead of the empty value in XercesC?
Here's a sample XML file:
<doc a="&foo;"></doc>
Entity foo is undefined, so when I call getName() on the corresponding attr in attList inside XMLDocumentHandler::startElement, an empty string is returned. I would, however, like to somehow extract the entity name that I could display instead of the missing value. I would like to be able to print out something like:
Attribute name: a.
Attribute value: &foo;.

I've searched the library code but didn't come up with any ideas how to do it.
